# Processing simoultaneously multiple occurrences in Scala foreach

Tags: scala

Assume I have the following array:

```
val a = Array(12, 7, 15, 2, 20, 9)
```

and I process it with a foreach:

```
a.foreach {  x =>  // some code }
```

Say when I'm processing the second element, 7, I need information about the next one, in this case 15. How can I get that information if I only have access to the occurrence that's been processed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `.sliding(2)` before `.map`/`.foreach`:

```
scala> a.sliding(2).foreach { 
         case Array(current, next) => println(s"current is $current, next is $next")
       }
current is 12, next is 7
current is 7, next is 15
current is 15, next is 2
current is 2, next is 20
current is 20, next is 9
```

Note however that the last element (`9`) is never reached as `current`, because there wouldn't be any `next` value to use.
Depending on what you want to do accessing the elements using indices might by the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

`Array` has random access, so it's cheap to use `apply` to get an element. You could iterate over the indices instead.

```
val a = Array(12, 7, 15, 2, 20, 9)

a.indices.foreach { i =>
  if (a(i) == 7 && i + 1 < a.length) {
    val next = a(i + 1)
    println(s"next element is $next")
  }
}
```

Comment: Just corrected `i < a.length` to `i + 1 < a.length`, which shows that this is error prone. Better go for the `sliding` approach in Marth's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the following element, you can zip `list.zip(list.take(1))`, or a `list.zipWithIndex` will allow you to know which index you are, and then iterate on the tuple.